How to find and ask mufti?
As a follow-up to Fees for a mufti
how can one find and ask a mufti?
Who can ask a mufti? Only Islamic people or others as well?
(I'm quite sure the tags for that can be improved, If someone can, please do so.)

Where and to whom can I ask for answers to my questions and doubts? seems to me relevant. I don't see how the tag [tag:muftirat] is relevant here since it is literally about things that break fast.

@Medi1Saif thank you for removing tags that I misunderstand.

Honestly, I wonder if we really need this specific tag.

Anyone can ask question from a mufti, but why a non-Muslim might require to need if he can do something or not is he was on his prayer, or things like that? I know there might be situation that someone need such data, but that would be exceptions as huge amount of questions are asked daily by millions of Muslims everyday.
But about how to find a mufti, if you live a Muslim country that should be as easy as finding a mosque, though maybe not that easy as not all mosques themselves have muftis good enough to answer to most of questions asked from them. Another more reliable method these days is to use internet, find a reliable institute and ask your question there. They might have forums to discuss things, might have chat, or might receive your answer and reply back within a few days. They even regularly give you the references they used to answer your question. Here is the address for such a website, which answers not limited to Fiqh (fatwa) only questions. There I know several other scholarly websites around religious issues, but almost all of them are in Persian (perhaps the 2nd language for Shia Muslims), maybe they have also English versions as well, but this one is the only one now I know of.

I did ask not so much for myself but for the many other people.
